# How Google Photos synchronization works with Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos, synchronization, google-plus-photos

When you allow;

Your mobile or desktop synchronize photos to your google+, google photos. These photos can show into your account drive within a folder called google photos.

Now when you synchronize your google drive to your windows system these photos will also synchronized and categorized in year->month->photos.

Now when you move photo inside this folder or create new folders inside it, then they get synchronized in web drive google photos. And if I'm correct this folder is synchronized with google photos. Then new folder should appear as albums in google photos, but this is not happening. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correct:  New folders created in Drive do not become albums in Photos.

This is a known limitation of the integration between Drive and Photos, documented here:   https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?hl=en-GB